# How to configure NGINX to serve a JSON API and a React.js on the same box

Tags: reactjs, nginx, phoenix-framework

I have been working on JSON API written in Elixir using the phoenix framework, and I successfully deployed yesterday.  However, the API is not that useful with out a web frontend, which I wrote one as well using React.js.

I'm deploying the phoenix API using a combination of distillery and gatling, and everything appears to be working when I test it using Postman.

Then I edited the nginx configuration file to loook like the following,

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/kegcopr_api**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kegcopr.chrisrjones.com;
  root /opt/Code/react/kegcopr-frontend/build;
  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/deployments/kegcopr_api/nginx.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:33725;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

}
```

I then created a `.env` file in the root of React.js project with the following line,

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:33725/api
```

Any help on how to get this configured would greatly be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I changed the `.env` file to,

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://kegcopr.chrisrjones.com/api
```

and ran the below command,

```
npm run build
```

but I am still not seeing the React.js frontend display in the browser.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work with this? Also, shouldn't `REACT_APP_API_URL` be `http://kegcopr.chrisrjones.com/api` assuming this nginx conf is proxying to Phoenix running on port 33725?

Comment: @Dogbert thanks for pointing that out.  And as of right now the React.js frontend isn't displaying in the browser.

Comment: Could you try this: https://gist.github.com/101e81da99416debbe0849be51afacf4? I use something similar to serve static files using nginx and proxying other requests to Phoenix.

Comment: @Dogbert tried the gist your provided, still seeing `page not found`

Comment: @Dogbert it appears your solution is working now.  Probably related to browser cache.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the `root` directory, but you're sending all requests unconditionally to `localhost:33725`. If you want to serve static files from the `root` directory and pass all other requests to the `proxy_pass`, you can use `try_files` like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:33725;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

`try_files` will try to locate the file within `root` with the same name as the URL, and if it fails to find a file, it'll pass the request to `@proxy`, which will pass it to the Phoenix app running on `localhost:33725`.