# Nginx - send index.html on all routes other than /api

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, nginx-upstreams

I am using Nginx as reverse proxy to serve  react application and backend api.

```
upstream api {
  server localhost:5000;
}




server {

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com  www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }

// Ideally, the solution should redirect this routes to use /var/www/example.com/html/index.html
// 1. example.com/teams/1 -> would resolve into react app being served (/var/www/example.com/html/index.html)
// 2. example.com/homepage -> would resolve into react app being served (/var/www/example.com/html/index.html)
// 3. example.com/api/teams/1 -> would resolve into upstream api (localhost:5000/teams/1)

  
}
```

How can I achieve something like this within Nginx?

Comment: Change `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri /index.html;`

Comment: Already asked and answered - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944777/5962802